# ASP.NET: JavaScript object Component for Composite Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, composite

I have two doubts:

**1.** I would like to add some client side support for my server composite control but I can't find the correct way to add JavaScript to him.

**2.** Another feature I would like to have for the client-side support is to have my JavaScript component object returned through $find(id, parent) (shortcut to findComponent method of the Sys.Application).

Can anyone help me? I'm not finding clear information about this :|

Regards,

Rodrigo S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the best article I've seen in the matter for beginners is [ASP.NET AJAX Control Development](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/ASPNETAJAXControlDevelopment.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that gets here looking for the same information, I was looking for, precisely, this information:

- [Creating Client Components and Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386565.aspx)

  - Creating Custom AJAX Client Controls (Link: ~/bb398906.aspx)
- Adding Client Capabilities to a Web Server Control (Link: ~/bb386450.aspx)

Regards,

Rodrigo S.